# Influence of OUTER table size in Hash-Join on the amount of spilled data

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I have a question about Err: "number of workfiles per segment limit exceeded"

I know that this error is generated when the large amount of data is spilled
to the disk, and too many workfiles are created. One of the reasons is large
Hash tables created during the hashjoin. It is common that hash tables are 
generated for inner tables in join, so I cant understand the following fact:

I have Left HashJoin of two tables Outer one and Inner one, the distribution
of both this tables is not very good (Outer table have mainly NULLs in destribution key, Inner table have mainly ' ' value in destribution key, the distribution key and join key for both tables are the same).

1) When I try to join this tables without filter condition expectedly it falls
with "number of workfiles per query limit exceeded" on segment where ' ' values are stored in Inner relation(95 segment in attachment in comments).

2) I remove all ' ' values with join condition from INNER 
table on purpose to reduce HashTable. After that the query shows different behavior: If DB is higly loaded the query falls with error: "number of workfiles per segment limit exceeded" on 10-th segment, where NULLs in Outer relation are stored. IF DB is normally loaded the query is executed without problems(as you can see in attach it spills on 10-th segment)

3) I remove NULLs and ' ' values both from OUTER and INNER table and it works!
I whant to mention that size of INNER table is still the same as in example
"2)" after removing all ' ' from Outer relation

I've made a conclusion, that OUTER Table have an influence on amount of spilled data to the disk.

So the question is: 
How does the size of Outer table influence on amount of spilled to the disk data? 
Is there any dependence between Outer table size and HashTable
size? 
For what purposes w_mem is used in Hash_Join except generating the HashTable?

Im asking this because I cant find any detailed enough information abot HashJoin algorithm,
and all desriptions of HashJoin algorithm and spilled_files I've found looks like: 
"Scan by Hash on Hash_table (which biuld on Inner relation) during the SeqScan on OUTER table" and "spill_files spilled when you have large HashTables"
Maybe Someone have links on more complex description of basic DB operations?

Comment: `What is the dependence between Outer table size and HashTable size?` The expected number of values.

Comment: The expected number of values for inner relation?

Comment: Please provide the DDL for the tables, the SQL Query, and the row count per segment by distributed key for each table. e.g. select gp_segment_id, count(*) from table_name group by gp_segment_id order by 1;

Comment: @JonRoberts, I'll do this a bit later, also i'll provide Explain Analyze. I've noticed that my question conditions where inaccurate. I have not NULLs, but ' ' in inner relation. And the ability of my query to process depend on workload of database.

Comment: @JonRoberts - here it is https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7ycnrlit7oamgg/Stack_Q.rar?dl=0,

Comment: @JonRoberts, now Im a bit confused, because memory_used and memory_wanted are the same in both explains, but in one of it data spilled on 10-th segment, where Nulls for Outer are stored

Comment: Can you just update the question to include the information?

Comment: @JonRoberts, question updated

Comment: When tables are joined together that require more memory than is available, the database will create workfiles up to a limit based on the GUC gp_workfile_limit_files_per_query which you have exceeded.  The Admin Guide covers this but you basically need to either allocate more statement memory and/or fix any skew issues you have.  Without the DDL and SQL statement, I can't help much more.

Comment: @JonRoberts I provided DDL and script by link on dropbox in comments,

Comment: @JonRoberts I can't provide Data

Comment: @Zhenek you are supposed to provide the entire question without attachment on Stackoverflow so that readers can see the full question and answers.  I also couldn't access the dropbox files.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below steps

```
> set optimizer=off;
> Run your Query
> set optimizer=on;
```

Sometimes, the optimizer doesn't make a good plan for our queries and then Greenplum makes many worker files which gives this error.